# Android RelativeLayout views are not visible

Tags: android, layout

I'm new to android , and I have a problem with relativeLayout ,All the views inside the relative Lyout are not showing : editTexts and spinners , and I can't see where the error is :(

here is the xml file :

```
        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="0.01"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:padding="10dp" >

            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/fname"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1.0"
                android:hint="@string/fname"
                android:inputType="text"
                android:textSize="12sp" 
                />

            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/lname"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1.0"
                android:hint="@string/lname"
                android:inputType="text"
                android:textSize="12sp" 
                android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/fname"

                />

            <Spinner
                android:id="@+id/catspin"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:entries="@array/cat"
                android:prompt="@string/cat" 
                android:layout_below="@+id/fname"

                />

            <Spinner
                android:id="@+id/rolespin"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:entries="@array/role"
                android:prompt="@string/role" 
                android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/catspin"

                />

            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/oparea"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1.0"
                android:hint="@string/oparea"
                android:inputType="text"
                android:textSize="12sp" 
                android:layout_below="@+id/catspin"

                />

            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/job"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1.0"
                android:hint="@string/job"
                android:inputType="text"
                android:textSize="12sp" 
                android:layout_below="@+id/oparea"

                />

             <EditText
                android:id="@+id/phone"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1.0"
                android:hint="@string/phone"
                android:inputType="text"
                android:textSize="12sp"
                android:layout_below="@+id/job"

                />

             <EditText
                android:id="@+id/email"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1.0"
                android:hint="@string/email"
                android:inputType="text"
                android:textSize="12sp" 
                android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/phone"

                />



        </RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: Have you tried removing `android:layout_weight` attributes? You've got it set to 0.01 at th root layout.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:padding="10dp" 
            xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/fname"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:hint="@string/fname"
                android:inputType="text"
                android:textSize="12sp" 
                />

            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/lname"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:hint="@string/lname"
                android:inputType="text"
                android:textSize="12sp" 
                android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/fname"

                />

            <Spinner
                android:id="@+id/catspin"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:entries="@array/cat"
                android:prompt="@string/cat" 
                android:layout_below="@+id/fname"

                />

            <Spinner
                android:id="@+id/rolespin"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:entries="@array/role"
                android:prompt="@string/role" 
                android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/catspin"

                />

            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/oparea"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1.0"
                android:hint="@string/oparea"
                android:inputType="text"
                android:textSize="12sp" 
                android:layout_below="@+id/catspin"

                />

            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/job"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1.0"
                android:hint="@string/job"
                android:inputType="text"
                android:textSize="12sp" 
                android:layout_below="@+id/oparea"

                />

             <EditText
                android:id="@+id/phone"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1.0"
                android:hint="@string/phone"
                android:inputType="text"
                android:textSize="12sp"
                android:layout_below="@+id/job"

                />

             <EditText
                android:id="@+id/email"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1.0"
                android:hint="@string/email"
                android:inputType="text"
                android:textSize="12sp" 
                android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/phone"

                />



        </RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 4):

`layout_weight` does not work in a `RelativeLayout`, it's for `LinearLayout`s. So your `EditText`s and `Spinner`s are all `0dp` wide and thus not visible.

Answer (score 0):

Remove `android:layout_weight="0.01" android:orientation="horizontal"` this two properties from your `RelativeLayout` and then check.

`android:layout_weight` doesn't work in a `RelativeLayout`, it's for `LinearLayout`. So make your EditTexts and Spinner's `android:layout_width="wrap_content"`.

Answer (score -2):

Linear layout you can assign orientation but in relative layouts its overlap one another so you need to make id for each and make layout_below in each views